# Facebook sharer do not find an url that exist

Tags: android, facebook

I have a strange problem, I have uploaded an app to Google play, now I want to add a share button to this app, the share button works great with other app urls but do not work with the url of my app.

This is the facebook share link with my app (do not work) : 
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.OziosaFun.Love.Frames

This is the facebook share link with other app (it works):
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote

I uploaded the app 2 days ago. This is very strange :S

Answer (score 0):

- You can debug the facebook cache with this debugger:
  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
- The result was cached from April 14 6:07pm

[image: FacebookCache]

- You have to click fetch new Information, to refresh the cache. Then the share dialog should work as expected.

[image]